# Initialize Dictionary in .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, compact-framework

Is there a simple way to initialize a dictionary that is a property like in [.Net 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx) or do I need to add the elements in the class's constructor?

My aim is to have a static map of codes mapping to string representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to initialize your `Dictionary` at class constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If your class is static you can do it in a static constructor.

```
static myclass()
{
    //Do stuff here?!
}
```

If it's not, do it in your instance constructor?

Comment: No nifty way like in C3 3.0+?

Answer (score 1):

The Collection Initializer syntax is only available for Dictionaries in .NET 3.5 and going forward.

FTA:

> This feature (collection
>   initialization) requires the C# 3.0
>   compiler wich was introduced with
>   Visual Studio 2008 and only works with
>   .NET 3.5 or later. Static
>   initialization only works for arrays
>   in previous versions.

However, you're not limited to adding the elements in your classes constructor.  You can add then any time you want, you just can't do it using collection initialization.

Comment: I saw that, but wanted to see if there was a method I was not familiar with. Thanks.

Comment: the requirement is C# 3.0, not .NET 3.5, because it works (with the C# 3.0 compiler) even if targeting .Net 2.0